# how to apply ssl certificate to a linux scaleset

Tags: azure

What is the best way to update ssl in Azure Scaleset running ubuntu. I have to update ssl certificate across all vms in a scaleset and also make sure that new instances created have the new ssl.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> also make sure that new instances created have the new ssl.

As we know, Azure VMSS create new instances with your custom image, so if you want new instances with new SSL, we need to update the VHD or image.

In your scenario, we can use custom image which have new SSL certificate to **update** Azure VMSS.

We can roll out an OS update to an Azure virtual machine scale set without any downtime, but this **not** work for VMSS create from Azure marketplace(like the screenshot).

[image]

Here a example updates a windows virtual machine scale set, after updating the model, it does an update one virtual machine instance at a time.

```
$rgname = "myrg"
$vmssname = "myvmss"
$newversion = "4.0.20160229"
$instanceid = "1"

# get the VMSS model
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VMScaleSetName $vmssname

# set the new version in the model data
$vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.version = $newversion

# update the virtual machine scale set model
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $vmssname -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss

# now start updating instances
Update-AzureRmVmssInstance -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VMScaleSetName $vmssname -InstanceId $instanceId
```

If your VMSS create with VHD, we should use this PowerShell script:

```
# set the new version in the model data
$vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.osDisk.image.uri= $newURI
```

If your VMSS create with image(managed disk), we should use this script:

```
# set the new version in the model data
$vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.id = $newImageReference
```

More information about update Azure VMSS, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set).

Comment: thanks for the help. To update the image will we have to first host the image as a vm and update the certificate and then create another image? Is this the process?

Comment: @kumar Yes, you are right, we should create another image, create a new VM and SSL, then sysprep it and create image with it.

Comment: also you please elaborate on $vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.version. I used manged disk and understand $vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.id = $newImageReference

Comment: @kumar Does your VMSS create from Azure marketplace?

Comment: @kumar we should use `$vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.id = $newImageReference` to replace `$vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.ve‌​rsion`.

Comment: I am using a custom image managed disk VMSS. So i should use $vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.id = $newImageReference correct? When should I use $vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.ve‌​‌​rsion, Azure marketplace vm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71336/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-kumar).

Comment: @kumar You are right, managed disk should use new image. `$vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.ve‌​‌​‌​rsion` just update OS version, the image from Azure marketplace. That just an example to update OS version:)